# Material-UI definition list

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to achieve the following using React Material-UI, minus the expansion carets on the right:

[image: list with right items]

Here's the spec on the Google page. https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#expansion-panels-usage

I've found that there's no exact component for this style. I basically have a bunch of summary data that I want to display but I feel like a Table or just a straight Material List with subheadings is not appropriate. I guess I really want a html definition list basically. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Just looking for really an idea of how I could do it with the existing material components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm kinda late to the party, but here's how I'll do it:

```
<Grid 
  container
  component='dl' // mount a Definition List
  spacing={2}>
  <Grid item>
    <Typography component='dt' variant='h6'> 
      Some Heading or Definition Term
    </Typography>
    <Typography component='dd' variant='body2'>
      Some Definition data
    </Typography>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I implemented a similar solution as above. You can switch the containers around to suit your specific need.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Paper component of react material ui.

> http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/paper

Fill in the data as a Row with each row having border-bottom css enabled.

```
<Paper>
  <div style={{borderTop: '1px solid #dce0e0'>
   // fill in each data as a column of a specified width
  </div>
</Paper>
```

Check out this fiddle.. It's a bit messy but you will get the gist.

> https://jsfiddle.net/cmaL8jku/

Comment: It's working for me.. I'm not sure why it isn't for you.. :P

Answer (score 0):

There is a material-ui component **Card**, you can use that. It has the same expand/collapse feature.

Use it like this:

```
<Card>

    <CardHeader
        title="Without Avatar"
        subtitle="Subtitle"
        actAsExpander={true}
        showExpandableButton={true}
    />

    <CardActions>
        <FlatButton label="Action1" />
        <FlatButton label="Action2" />
    </CardActions>

    <CardText expandable={true}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
        Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
        Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
    </CardText>

</Card>
```

Put the content inside CartText, define the header. There are bool variable **actAsExpander, showExpandableButton** by which you can control the expand/collapse feature. All the elements of Card are options means if you don't want the card action remove that same for other elements also.

Check the [DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card) for more details on Card.

Comment: try this, let me know if you need any help in this.

Comment: So I would just have multiple cards? Or would I put all the items in one card? I feel like the card is just a container. Would I have to move the CardText to the right?

Comment: yes, card is just a container, you can use multiple card, if you put all the items in one card then only one card will expand/collapse, if you want to make a list where many items can be expandable then use multiple cards.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use makeStyles and style it to your needs.

```
import makeStyles from '@mui/styles/makeStyles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  definitionList: {
    '& > dt': theme.typography.body1,
    '& > dd': theme.typography.body2,
  },
}));

export const MyComponent: React.FC = observer(() => {
  const classes = useStyles();
```

Then simply add the class to your dl.

```
<dl className={classes.definitionList}>

  <dt>Given Name:</dt>
  <dd>{profile.givenName}</dd>

  <dt>Surname:</dt>
  <dd>{profile.surname}</dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest approach to me in theory, but `@mui/styles` [has been deprecated](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/). Would be great to see how to do the equivalent in mui v5+.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of `Paper` for the container style, `Stack` for each item, and `Divider` for the separator line.

```js
const DefinitionItem = ({ label, children }: {
  label: React.ReactNode;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => (
  <Stack direction="row" width="100%" p={2} gap={2}>
    <Typography component="dt" variant="body1" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      {label}
    </Typography>
    <Typography component="dd" variant="body1">
      {children}
    </Typography>
  </Stack>
);

const DefinitionList = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <Paper>
    <Stack component="dl" divider={<Divider />}>
      {children}
    </Stack>
  </Paper>
);
```

Can be used via the following:

```
<DefinitionList>
  <DefinitionItem label="Trip Name">Caribbean Cruise</DefinitionItem>
  <DefinitionItem label="Location">Barbados</DefinitionItem>
  <DefinitionItem label="Start and end dates">
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={6}>
      <>Start Date: Today</>
      <>End Date: Tomorrow</>
    </Stack>
  </DefinitionItem>
</DefinitionList>
```